# Disabling linux user password prompts when accessing encrypted drives (polkit conf?)

Tags: password, encryption, security, luks, policykit

I just created a new ext4 partition on a new drive and decided to use LUKS to encrypt it. I entered a password to use for encryption and the partition was created. So far, so good.

However, I have the drive open in Nautilus. Every time I move away from that window and come back to it, it asks me my **user** password (not the encryption password, but the password of my user on the local linux machine).

My expectation was that I would have to provide the encryption password once - when mounting the disk - and never again, and in particular, never have to provide linux user credentials to access the drive.

What I'm seeing would perhaps make sense in a military network, but is ridiculous in a home environment. How do I disable all password prompts beyond the first prompt for the encryption password?

This is Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, used gnome-disks to manage partitions. The drive is an external USB drive. I mounted it like any external memory, using Nautilus. I did not touch `/etc/fstab`, but I wouldn't expect I that I should touch it any more than I would for a USB key. The drive is accessible under `/media/<myusername>/<external drive name>`. The permissions on `/media/<myusername>` are `drwx------` and it belongs to my user and my group.

Apparently, this behaviour is controlled by Polkit. I get the impression that I need to change ResultActive or ResultInactive in the encryption-related section to one of yes, no, auth_self, auth_self_keep. The docs are [here](https://freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest), but I don't see where these terms are defined, in particular active and inactive and it doesn't help that the docs are not searchable. Any hints?

[This article](https://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Assigning-Privileges-with-sudo-and-PolicyKit) provides a great overview of allowed params and values, shedding some more light on the subject, but still no luck. I tried with `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-unlock.pkla`:

```
[Test]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;
ResultAny=yes
```

Comment: It sounds like the mount point of the encrypted partition has the "wrong" permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, Used gnome-disks to manage partitions. The drive is an external USB drive. I mounted it like any external memory, using Nautilus. I did not touch `/etc/fstab`, but I wouldn't expect I that I should touch it any more than I would for a USB key. The drive is accessible under `/media/<myusername>/<external drive name>`. The permissions on `/media/<myusername>` are `drwx------` and it belongs to my user and my group.

Comment: Apparently, this behaviour is controlled by Polkit. I get the impression that I need to change `ResultActive` or `ResultInactive` in the encryption-related section to one of `yes, no, auth_self, auth_self_keep`. The docs are here (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/), but I don't see where these terms are defined, in particular `active` and `inactive` and it doesn't help that the docs are not searchable. Any hints?

Comment: This article (https://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Assigning-Privileges-with-sudo-and-PolicyKit) provides a great overview of allowed params and values, shedding some more light on the subject, but still no luck.

I tried with `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-unlock.pkla`:
`[Test]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;
ResultAny=yes`

Comment: Fun fact: it seems to just be Nautilus. If I access the drive from e.g. Thunar or from a terminal, I can just access everything, no questions asked. This is a lovely workaround, but I'd still love to fix this with Nautilus, now that I'm half way down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Please put all the information you have in comments in your question. The comments are mainly for us to ask for clarifications. From your comments it sounds like a bug in Nautilus. See if a bug report has been filed. If yes, add your name to the list of people affected by this bug. If not, consider [filing a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).